# Why does changing the .env password not work in supabase

Tags: docker, supabase

Why does changing the `.env` file  password not work in Supabase

I changed content like this

```
DASHBOARD_USERNAME=admin
DASHBOARD_PASSWORD=s123456!!!@
```

Then I run `docker compose restart`

Now I login the dashboard with the new username and password, but it's not working! why?

I use the old (default) account and it is ok!

Comment: did you try ? `DASHBOARD_PASSWORD="s123456!!!@"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `docker compose restart`, try running `docker compose down` followed by `docker compose up`. This will recreate the volumes, syncing the changes you have made to your .env file

See [this docker forum thread](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-compose-not-synchronising-file-changes-in-volume/79177/5) for more information